# PHP - Saving Uploaded Image to Server

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest

I am trying to save an uploaded image from an iPhone to a server using PHP. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to handle the data request. This is my iPhone code:

```
[request setPostValue:someString forKey:@"string1"];
[request setPostValue:anotherString forKey:@"string2"];
[request addData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, 0.9)]
         withFileName:@"img.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"img"];

[request startSynchronous];
```

On the server side, I am using this PHP code currently to try saving the image to a folder on my server:

```
print_r($_FILES);

$folder = 'upload/';
$image_path = basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
echo $folder . $image_path . "\n";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $folder . $image_path)) {
    echo 'ok!';
} 
else {
    echo 'fail !';
}
```

The strings are uploaded just fine and when I `print_r()` i see the contents of the image array as I expect, but for some reason when trying to save the image, i am getting "fail !" printed to the console. What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: On what server are you storing the image? Do you have permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: looks like you are using a relative uploade path.  Try echo realpath($folder); to be sure you are uploading it where you think its being uploaded.

Comment: Thanks, ehudokai! That's what did it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following step before you move your image

```
if(!is_dir($folder))
{
   echo "Folder does not exist" ;

   if(!mkdir($folder))
   {
      echo "Attempt to create folder failed" ;
   }
}
else if(!is_writable($folder))
{
   echo "Folder nto writeable" ;

   if(!chmod($folder, 0755))
   {
        echo "Attempt to make writeable failed" ;
   }
}
 else {

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $folder . $image_path)) {
      echo 'ok!';
   }
   else {
    echo 'fail !';
   }    
}
```

What do you get ???

Comment: Thanks for that code. I added it and I get ok! but when i open the folder on the server it is empty.

Comment: This combined with ehudokai's advice of using `realpath($folder)` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please also remember to do security checks on the file being uploaded. For example, check the file types against a whitelist (jpeg, png, gif, etc)- I'm sure you don't want someone being able to upload a script to your website?

Also for the long term you would be better off manually creating the upload folder and setting the appropriate permissions as oppose to having the PHP script do it for you..

Comment: Yea that's actually what I ended up doing.