# just got done with an image upload php mysql

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I just had it working, then I thought I was done and it stopped working. if the file is not an image, I'm trying to get it to kick out an error. here is the piece im talking about. any help would be gladly appreciated

```
$type_array = array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png','image/x-png'); //image types allowed
if(isset($_FILES['images'][$i]) and $_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '') { //check image
    if ($_FILES['images']['size'][$i] < 10240000) { //make sure file is larger than 10mb
        $type = $_FILES['images']['type'][$i]; //get the file types
        if (!in_array($type, $type_array)) { //make sure the images are allowed
            $errors[] = "Please check that you are uploading an image.";
            $show_errors = 'show';
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Please make sure each file is less than 10MB.";
        $show_errors = 'show';
        exit;
    }
} //image checked
```

Comment: your indentation is horrible to read. So what's the problem? I'm not convinced it's in that code segment.

Comment: Why have an array of errors and then exit after putting one value into it? Also, your `$show` variable is redundant - use `if(count($errors)) {//Show Errors Here}` (or if you don't initialise it, `if(isset($errors)){...}` )

Comment: How did it "stop working"? Does it allow all kinds of files?

Comment: it looks like should work.....you can see this tutorial for uploading image...http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/

Comment: @Basic in my html code I have if(isset($error)) which show any error in the array.

Comment: @Keezy In that case, may I ask what the `$show_errors = 'show';` line does?

Comment: I mean you're probably right, im new to this so I just wanted to set the variable. I could of just put $show_errors = ''; but if the variable is set then all the errors in the array will show out in a error div, thats all. if(isset($error)) {show errors using the div}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the errors

A. `$_FILES ['images'] ['size'] [$i]` would only work if you are expecting multiple image upload

Solution

You should just use `$_FILES ['images'] ['size']`

B. The Follow Script is wrong

```
 if (isset ( $_FILES ['images'] [$i] ) and $_FILES ['images'] ['name'] [$i] != '') { // check
```

Just use

```
  if($_FILES['images']['error'] == 0){
```

If you are dealing with multiple images .. have give to many examples here before see .

[limiting the checking condition while uploading swf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151960/limiting-the-checking-condition-while-uploading-swf-files/10152156#10152156)

[PHP - Saving Uploaded Image to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423449/php-saving-uploaded-image-to-server/9423524#9423524)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "exit;". It ends all PHP execution and your code after that won't run.